# Permutizer of a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is defined to be the subgroup generated by all cyclic subgroups of $G$ that permute with $H$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$. The permutizer of a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is defined to be the subgroup generated by all cyclic subgroups of $G$ that permute with $H$,
i.e., $P_G(H)= \langle x \in G \mid \langle x \rangle H = H \langle x \rangle \rangle$, denoted by $P_G(H)$. I need an example to check the following three sentences:

1) $N_G(H) \leq P_G(H)$.

2) $P_{G/N}(HN/N) \geq P_G(H)N/N$.

3) if $N \leq H$ then $P_{G/N}(H/N) = P_G(H)/N$.

I have proved these sentences but I don't have an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for examples such as the following ones.

1. Let $G$ be the nonabelian group of order $p^{3}$ and exponent $p^{2}$, for $p$ an odd prime. Let $H$ be a subgroup of order $p$ which is not normal. Then $N_{G}(H)$ has order $p^{2}$, but $P_{G}(H) = G$. This shows that in $N_G(H) \leq P_G(H)$ equality need not hold.
2. Let $G$ be the nonabelian group of order $p^{3}$ and exponent $p$, for $p$ a prime. Let $H$ be a subgroup of order $p$ which is not normal, and let $N$ be the unique normal subgroup of order $p$. Then $P_{G}(H) = HN$, so that $P_G(H)N/N = HN/N$ has order $p$. But $G/N$ is abelian, so $P_{G/N}(HN/N)$ has order $p^{2}$.
   This shows that in $P_{G/N}(HN/N) \geq P_G(H)N/N$ equality need not hold.